# A movie where thorns sting a woman's feet while she's trying to infiltrate some base

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was a scene in a movie that I watched in the 2000's or early 2010's (possibly earlier). Regardless, it wasn't recent, and I don't remember much of it, only images.

I know the leading role is a woman (I think she had black hair). This woman has some robot-like behaviors (I don't think she is a robot but she is acts as though controlled and fights really well). The woman and some other people are trying to infiltrate a base. They are trying to prevent something, kill the people in charge, or something.

I remember when they are trying to get in, there's the main woman and her friend in a field full of grass. They're fighting with the enemy but thorns erupt from the ground, and the thorns sting one of the woman's feet.

Comment: A related story, and an early example of a failure of stealth technology (invaders removing their boots to eliminate noise) gave rise to the thistle becoming the national emblem of the Scots...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thistle#Heraldry

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Could be [*Aeon Flux*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0402022/) (2005)?

Charlize Theron's character, the main protagonist, and Sithandra, whose feet have been modified to be hands, are trying to cross a grassy area which is 'spiky'. There are elements of cloning in the plot as well.

Comment: ["*In 2011, a deadly pathogenic virus has killed 99% of the Earth's population, forcing the survivors to regroup and scatter across the Earth.*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86on_Flux_(film)) Only ten years out then.